# codenameone iOS build freezes

Tags: codenameone

I have small app that I built with Codename One, it runs ok in the simulator and on Android devices. But it freezes on my iPhone. I used the iOS-debug in Netbeans to create the iOS build. I did some testing using the Dialog.show to find were it is freezing on my iPhone 12. The app sends a request to a web service and I receive the return data ok, but it freezes when parsing the JSON data to a map. I works in the simulator and on Android devices. I put a Dialog wright before the parsing and another after the parse to map is done. I never see the that Dialog because it freezing at that point. Below is the code.

```
    // --- call webservice Points Lookup WEBR419r2 ---
    Response<String> response = Rest.post(PointsLookup_URL).jsonContent()
            .body(jsonInput).getAsString();
    System.out.println(response.getResponseCode());
    //Dialog.show("Rest reply 1", "getResponseCode", "OK", null);
    String returnData = response.getResponseData();
    System.out.println(returnData);
    Dialog.show("Rest reply 1", returnData.substring(0, 80), "OK", null);
        
    JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
    try(Reader r = new InputStreamReader(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(returnData.getBytes()))) {
        map = json.parseJSON(r);
        Dialog.show("JSON map 2", map.toString(), "OK", null);
        System.out.println("*** WEB SERVICE call ok ***");
        Dialog.show("Reader  2", "*** WEB SERVICE call ok ***", "OK", null);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex);
        Dialog.show("Rest reply 2E", ex.toString(), "OK", null);
    }
```

I ran the app in the simulator and tested it on a android and iPhone.

Comment: If I understand correctly only dialog 1 is showing and includes valid JSON in it. In that case try the following: Change the catch to catch `Throwable`. Also, how big is the JSON? 
Also I suggest making this fix: `new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(returnData.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8")`.

Comment: HI, Shai, I made the changes and the program is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException after the Dialog shows the return data. This is were the json parse to map happens. The return json data is less than 1K. I also tried the build without the java 8 hint. Agin it works in the simulator and android.

Comment: How is the variable `json` initialized? Is it possible that it's `null`?

Comment: HI, Shai, I got it working. I thought it was the jsonParser so I created my own parsing method and it still failed. Then I realized it had to be something with the map that I was doing.  System.out.println(map.toString). So I remarked out all of map print lines and it how works on the iPhone. Thanks

Comment: That's interesting. Looking at the code I don't see why that specific printing would fail on iOS. Regardless I suggest using `Log.p()` and never `System.out`.